# How to return value within nested async calls?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, completionhandler

Assuming "request" is defined and valid

```
func1()
// start using "X"

func func1() {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        // code, that eventually gets some values "a" and "b"
        self.func2(a: a, b: b)
    }.resume()
}

func func2(a: String, b: String) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // some UI stuff that needs to be done on the main thread
        self.func3(a: a, b: b)
    }
}

func func3(a: String, b: String) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        // code, that eventually gets a value "X"
        // HOW TO RETURN "X" ALL THE WAY BACK WHERE func1() IS CALLED?
    }.resume()
}
```

I just typed this up manually, so there may be typos and other syntax errors (feel free to point them out)

So I have a few functions that I need to run one after another, which I can do, however, the last function generates a value "X", which is the value that I want. How can I return "X" from `func3()` all the way back to where `func1()` is called so that I can carry on and use it?

Comment: Do you understand that you can't `return` the value normally because the code is async, and have to use completion handlers? Are you asking about how to use completion handlers?

Answer (score 0):

Give completion handlers to every function in the chain. It's easier to start with `func3`.

```
func func3(a: String, b: String, completion: @escaping (TypeOfX) -> Void) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        // code, that eventually gets a value "X"
        let x = getX()
        completion(x)
    }.resume()
}
```

And then `func2` and `func1` are forced to change...

```
func func2(a: String, b: String, completion: @escaping  (TypeOfX) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // some UI stuff that needs to be done on the main thread
        self.func3(a: a, b: b, completion: completion)
    }
}

func func1(completion: @escaping (TypeOfX) -> Void) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        // code, that eventually gets some values "a" and "b"
        self.func2(a: a, b: b, completion: completion)
    }.resume()
}
```

And finally the caller can pass a closure and use `x` there:

```
func1 {
    x in
    // use x here!
}
// Note that you can't use x here, outside the closure, because this line will be run 
// immediately after func1 returns, and before you get x
```

EDIT:

If you want to use `x` elsewhere, you can pass it to a method (and optionally store it in a property). Here are two ways. Which way you choose depends highly on the context - what `func1` is responsible for, where is it called, etc.

---

```
var x: TypeOfX?

...

func1 {
    x in
    // doesn't have to be "self.", could be on any object, really
    self.x = x
    self.didRemotelyGetX()
}

...

func didRemotelyGetX() {
    // use x here...
}
```

---

```
var x: TypeOfX?

...

func1 {
    x in
    self.didRemotelyGetX(x)
}

...

func didRemotelyGetX(_ x: TypeOfX) {
    // use x here...
    // self.x = x // do this if you want
}
```

Comment: thank you for this! i was able to do this before asking the question, however i left out my completion handlers because i wasn't sure if there was a better way. my question is that how can i set it up so that i CAN use "x" outside the closure?

edit: deleted my other comment but i see it was answered already so ill put it back: i pointed out that the completions should be @escaping

Comment: @ooh In the closure, you can assign `x` to a global variable or something, I guess... But you still need to wait for the code that gets `x` to be executed. How do you know when that is (reliably)? Well, the completion handler... You can also call another method in the completion handler and pass `x` to it. Does that count as "outside the completion handler"? Whatever you do, it will probably trace back to the completion handler.

Comment: So if "x" is a value that is assigned to a class property, and an instance of the class is declared elsewhere (a view controller), how I ensure that X is set before trying to use it in the view controller? Tempted to throw in a `while classInstance.X == nil {}` but surely there is a better way. (You may have addressed this and I may have misunderstood)

Comment: @ooh Quoting my previous comment: "How do you know when that is (reliably)? Well, the completion handler..." So in the completion handler, you would set the property, and then maybe call a method of the VC to tell the VC that the property is set.

Comment: So what would the code in the VC look like? I have `let a = ClassName()` and want to use `a.X`. Would there be some sort of while loop to check if it is set? I don't understand how to utilize this method telling the VC it is set as far as the code written. Sorry to be annoying, just having a hard time picturing this code-wise. Maybe a quick writeup of sample code would help.

Comment: @ooh It is very hard to suggest anything without knowing what `func1`, `func2` etc actually do, and where you are calling these things. But see the edit anyway :)